# Best practices for exposing "expensive" Observables in RxJava

Tags: rx-java

I'm new to RxJava and trying to determine common idioms and best practices.

Say I've got a `Foo` class that emits `Bar`s (incomplete and oversimplified for the moment):

```java
class Foo {
    public Subscriber barSubscriber;
    public Observable<Bar> getBarObservable = (...details omitted...)

    private void someMethod() {
        // emit a Bar
        barSubscriber.onNext(bar); 
    }
}
```

Other objects that want to subscribe to those `Bars` do so by calling

```java
foo.getBarObservable().subscribe(...);
```

Let's say that producing and emitting `Bar`s is "expensive". To avoid doing this when there are no more subscribers, Foo's `getBarObservable` could expose a connectable, ref-counted `Observable` like so (using `share()`):

```java
class Foo {
    private Subscriber barSubscriber;
    private Observable<Bar> barObservable =  Observable.create(
            new Observable.OnSubscribe<Bar>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Subscriber<? super Bar> subscriber) {
                    Foo.this.subscriber = subscriber;
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            runUntilUnsubscribed();
                        }
                    }).start();

                }
            }
    ).share();

    public Observable<Bar> getBarObservable() {
        return barObservable;
    }

    public void runUntilUnsubscribed(} {
        while(!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {

            /* do some heavy stuff that produces a Bar.  If, when a 
               Bar is ready, we still have subscribers, emit the Bar */

            if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) 
                subscriber.onNext(bar);
        }
    }
}
```

Most of the examples and tutorials I've seen create `Observable`s inline on-the-fly in the same chunk of code that subscribes to them, so it's not clear to me what the standard practices are in the more real-world scenario where the creation of the `Observable` and the subscription to it are in two different places.

1. For a class like `Foo` that doesn't want to know who its subscribers will be or how many subscribers it will have, is this the right approach?
2. It seems to me that this would be a very typical scenario - is it?  Or, at a high level, is this not the right way to think about exposing `Observable`s?  Are there drawbacks to using this approach routinely?
3. <s>It seems to me I need that little `if (subscriber == null && !subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) 
       subscriber.onNext(bar);` pattern every time I want to emit a `Bar`.  Is that also a common idiom, or is there a better way?</s> Nevermind, I don't need the null check..., not sure what I was thinking there.

Comment: You can use the various subject classes and PublishSubject is probably what you need.

Comment: @akamokd exposing a PublishSubject seems like it would work if you don't mind your Observable running "hot" continuously, but it doesn't seem like they are applicable to the case where you want your Observable to stop emitting when there are no subscribers.

Comment: nitpick, but isn't your check should be `if(subscriber != null .. .` instead of `subscriber == null` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example class can't really work: `setBar` can throw NPE if subscriber is `null`, the `runUntilUnsubscribed` references a missing bar field/value and is a busy loop that would emit the same value over and over.

You say creating a `Bar` is expensive, but its creation seems to be outside the `Foo` class and I guess you'd want to dispatch such value to the currently subscribed Subscribers. That is what PublishSubject is for:

```
class Foo {
    final PublishSubject<Bar> subject = PublishSubject.create();
    public void setBar(Bar bar) {
        subject.onNext(bar);
    }
    public Observable<Bar> getBarObservable() {
        return subject; // .asObservable() if you want to hide the subject
    }
}
```

If there aren't any subscribers, the bar set will just fall out and get garbage collected. If you'd like to retain the last value, use `BehaviorSubject` instead of a `PublishSubject`.

Otherwise, if you need to trigger the creation of the expensive Bar values when the subscriber arrives, you can use some jump-starting sequence with `share()`:

```
Observable.just(1)
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
.map(v -> createBar())
.share();
```

But the use of `share()` really depends on the intended lifecycle of each Bar value.

For example, if you want to store the bar until subscribers arrive, then do the heavy computations once and dispatch the results, you can have the following construct:

```
class Foo {
    final BehaviorSubject<Bar> subject = BehaviorSubject.create();
    final Observable<Bar> output = subject
        .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .doOnNext(bar -> expensiveInplaceComputation(bar))
        .take(1)
        .share();

    public void setBar(Bar bar) {
        subject.onNext(bar);
    }
    public Observable<Bar> getBarObservable() {
        return output;
    }
}
```

See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/akarnokd/dc3994e641db2e83d3dd) for a runnable example.

Comment: Regarding the setBar() method -- my first chunk of sample code was intentionally oversimplified, to introduce the discussion. The setter in that chunk was just a simple vehicle for triggering an emission, but it seems to have created confusion (my fault), so I've edited the question a little to clarify, thanks.  Assume the Bars are generated internally by the Foo class, e.g. as the result of processing an incoming data stream from another source.

Comment: Regarding an un`shared()`-ed `PublishSubject`, if I'm understanding its use case correctly, it doesn't seem like a fit -- I don't want to produce and emit `Bar`s until there are subscribers and I want to stop when there are no more subscribers.  Your last chunk of code seems to be what I'm looking for - (I think... I'm studying it).

Comment: OK, I think your last chunk is what I want, minus the `take(1)` - as long as there are subscribers, I want  `Foo` to keep producing and emitting `Bar`s to those subscribers.  If I'm understanding correctly, your approach would only emit one `Bar` to a given subscriber.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes it is roughly the correct approach. If `bar` in `Foo` needs to be shared to all subscribers, then use `.publish().refCount()` (or `share()` as you said). If not, then use a common Observable, which is by default "cold".
2. Exposing Observables is a common scenario. In a good reactive architecture most classes have only getters of Observables, because setters are inherently not reactive. Given a program or a class that works with setters, you can usually convert it to Observables and getters without affecting functionality. Observables and getters are a desirable approach because of some inversion of control. With setters, if `Foo` sets a value in `Baz`, you need to look at class `Foo` whenever you want to understand `Baz`. But with Observables and getters, `Baz` gets from `Foo` and `Baz` defines itself how it works, and `Foo` can be oblivious of `Baz`.
3. I haven't ever needed to use that `if` pattern. Also I rarely need `Observable.create()`. There are many Observable creation helpers (`from`, `interval`, `range`, `just`, to name a few) and Observable transformations (such as the all-powerful `flatMap`) that allow you to get very far in expressing new Observables. Also Subjects allow you to manually create Observables on the go.

Comment: regarding point 3: I've got a situation where, upon subscription, I want my observable to request a stream of input from a bluetooth connected device, process the incoming packets using a signal processing library, and emit the processed results.  As this is a heavy load on both the Android device and the connected device, I want to terminate the streaming as soon as there are no subscribers, and if I've received a packet but not processed it yet, I should skip the processing also if the subscription has ended.  Is there a different/better way to approach this  than the way I proposed?

Comment: "Stop underlying Observable behavior once there are no more subscribers": that's the use case for `.publish().refCount()`. Publish is used for sharing the exact same Observable instance all subscribers, and RefCount starts streaming (or processing the Observable) if there are at least 1 subscriber, and stops streaming when the number of subscribers goes from 1 to 0.

Comment: yes, I realize that - that's why I asked about using using share() -  shorthand for `.publish().refcount()`.